# <ltng:require not working in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app, aura

Component

```
     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.customScriptCSV != null}">       
        <ltng:require scripts="{!v.customScriptCSV}" afterScriptsLoaded=" 
                   {!c.doAfterScriptsLoaded}"/>        
    </aura:if>
    <aura:attribute name="customScriptCSV" type="String" access="global"/>
```

Helper js

```
  var customScriptCSV = $A.get('$Resource.' + 
            someobject.namespace__Custom_Script__c) + ","
            + $A.get('$Resource.LayoutJS') + "," + 
              $A.get('$Resource.ValidationJS') + "," + 
              $A.get('$Resource.LayoutProcessor');
            console.log("customScriptCSV: " + customScriptCSV);
            component.set("v.customScriptCSV" , customScriptCSV);
```

This works fine for normal users and it does not work in the community portal. I am getting values customScriptCSV in both cases. If I hard code the value in the component It works fine. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why set scripts value from client side controller?

Comment: I have to get values from server side and getting it from init and after setting up those values. 'someobject.namespace__Custom_Script__c' This one is Dynamic in nature